# D3 multiple donuts. adding unique class names

Tags: d3.js

I have a set of donut charts built and need to add a unique class name so that I can position them on the page.

Here's the code:

```js
    var data = [{
    "site": "hmi",
        "filled": 10,
        "capacity": 100
}, {
    "site": "poplar",
        "filled": 25,
        "capacity": 100
}, {
    "site": "cox",
        "filled": 50,
        "capacity": 100
}, {
    "site": "masonville",
        "filled": 75,
        "capacity": 100
}];

    var width = 200,
    height = 130,
    twoPi = 2 * Math.PI;

    var arc = d3.arc()
    .innerRadius(42.5)
    .outerRadius(50)
    .startAngle(0);

    var svg = d3.select("body").selectAll("svg")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("class", "donut") 
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

    svg.selectAll("svg")
svg.append("path")
    .datum({endAngle: twoPi})
    .style("fill", "#e6e6e6")
    .attr("d", arc);

    svg.selectAll("svg")
svg.append("path")
    .attr("d", arc.endAngle(function (d) {return (twoPi * (1 - ((d.capacity - d.filled) / d.capacity)));}))
    .style("fill", "orange");

    svg.append("text")
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function (d) {return d.site;});
```

```css
.total {
    font: 14px sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.label {
    font: 18px sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    fill: #c5c5c5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

[Link to CodePen Code](https://codepen.io/stevechezcp5/pen/RBmONz)

Comment: Add your code here, you can use the snippet tool or paste from your codepen and use the code tool to indent it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you're creating the plot, you can use the .attr tag to add an id element to it, which you can later manipulate via jquery or direct dom manipulation.

```
var svg = d3.select("body").selectAll("svg")
    .data(data)
.enter().append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height)
.attr("class", "donut") 
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")")
.attr("id", 'thing one');
```

Comment: please look at my codepen.  4 different svgs, and I want to move individually.  If i add an id, that is just for one item.

Comment: you can specify a function to generate different ones, so you can have something like .attr("id", (i) => {return ("chart" + i)})

Answer (score 0):

You can give the `svg` an `id` based on the datum attached `site` field or by sequence number (look at the comment line).

I have removed the `svg.selectAll("svg")` lines because they do nothing.

For drawing the complete circle you don't have to use the `datum()` just call the arc with the datum you want, unless you need to have the datum attached to the path for some reason.

```js
var data = [{
    "site": "hmi",
        "filled": 10,
        "capacity": 100
}, {
    "site": "poplar",
        "filled": 25,
        "capacity": 100
}, {
    "site": "cox",
        "filled": 50,
        "capacity": 100
}, {
    "site": "masonville",
        "filled": 75,
        "capacity": 100
}];

    var width = 200,
    height = 130,
    twoPi = 2 * Math.PI;

    var arc = d3.arc()
    .innerRadius(42.5)
    .outerRadius(50)
    .startAngle(0);

    var svg = d3.select("body").selectAll("svg")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("class", function (d) { return "donut" + " svg_" + d.site; } ) 
    //.attr("class", function (d, i) { return "donut" + " svg_" + i; } )
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

svg.append("path")
    .style("fill", "#e6e6e6")
    .attr("d", arc({endAngle: twoPi}));

svg.append("path")
    .attr("d", arc.endAngle(function (d) {return (twoPi * (1 - ((d.capacity - d.filled) / d.capacity)));}))
    .style("fill", "orange");

    svg.append("text")
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function (d) {return d.site;});
```

```css
.total {
    font: 14px sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.label {
    font: 18px sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    fill: #c5c5c5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

**Edit**

Changed it from unique ids to unique classes like the title asks.

Comment: @stvchez4534: just saw that you wanted unique classes instead of unique ids, changed the code